# DraftJS persisting data and controlling the data in render block

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

I am trying to fetch the `raw data` from the database saved with `convertToRaw` of Draft JS function and represent the `data` in the `editor` instead of `createEmpty` value.

Note : -

When I send props from parent component, child component gets null value initially unto the data is loaded.  How can I check this condition and set state?

Comment: please include an example of your code. Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: ```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Editor, EditorState} from 'draft-js';

class MyEditor extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    //Here I want to set editorState with propsData
    this.state = {editorState: EditorState.createEmpty()};
    this.onChange = (editorState) => this.setState({editorState});
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <Editor editorState={this.state.editorState} onChange={this.onChange} />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyEditor />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: you should probably edit the code in your question for better readability

Answer (score 0):

1. MyEditor have a raw state inside the component's props
2. you should not use createEmpty()
3. you should use [convertFromRaw](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-data-conversion#convertfromraw) to convert the raw state to contentState
4. and then use [createWithContent](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-editor-state#createwithcontent) to create a EditorState
5. done

Comment: Yeah, I have gone through the documentation. But, like I said the issues are with the null value receiving from props on initial load. 

`constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {
          editorState: props.abstract
            ? EditorState.createWithContent(convertFromRaw(props.abstract))
             : EditorState.createEmpty(decorator)
        };
    }`